# How to differentiate files with same name with different extension from two different folders? Python

Tags: python, list

**Problem Statement:-**
I have two folder with some data : `(1) ImageFile` , `(2) TextFile`

1. Image_File Folder: It contains only image files with .jpg extensions.

```
Image_File = [A.jpg, B.jpg, C.jpg, D.jpg, E.jpg]
```

2. TextFile Folder: It contains only text file with .txt extensions.

```
TextFile = [ A.txt, B.txt, C.txt]
```

**Expected Output:-**

The expected output should be as: `Result = [ D.jpg, E.jpg]`

Comment: Do you have already 2 lists with filenames? Or you want to get a list of files in specified folders?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, I have two folder(Folder1, Folder2) with same file names, The Folder1 contains files with .jpg extensions while Folder2 contains files with .txt extensions. I wants to save the files which are not common in folder1 and folder2 to the new folder. So that, from the contents of new folder we can conclude that which files are not similar in given two folders i.e. folder1 & folder2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have lists, you could use:

```
Image_File = ['A.jpg', 'B.jpg', 'C.jpg', 'D.jpg', 'E.jpg']
TextFile = ['A.txt', 'B.txt', 'C.txt']

basenames = {x.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)[0] for x in TextFile}
# {'A', 'B', 'C'}

Result = [x for x in Image_File if x.rsplit('.', 1)[0] not in basenames]
```

output: `['D.jpg', 'E.jpg']`